# Debugging multithreaded applications in Node.js Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging

I've got a Node.js console application I'm trying to attach the debugger to in Visual Studio 2015. It works well until I create a net server that listens for incoming data.

My console window starts off saying `Debugger listening on port 5858`, but when the net server is supposed to start it says `Press any key to continue...`. The output window then states:

```
The thread 'main thread' (0x1) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[13260] node.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)   'Access violation'.
```

My guess is that the multi-threading is messing with my debugger. I've tried running visual studio as admin as well as Node.js as it's giving me an 'Access violation', but with no luck. I can also confirm that my debugger is in fact working without creating the net server.

Does anyone know if there's a setting I'm missing to set a thread to use for debugging or steps to take in order for Visual Studio to understand debugging multiple threads in Node.js??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Bunyan logger module was causing the issue. I switched to a different logging module and now it works like a charm.